# @Streaming retrofit doesn't download file properly in release version (proguard enabled)

Tags: android

@Streaming retrofit doesn't download file properly in release version (proguard enabled) . Without @Streaming it works perfect in release version. With @Streaming it works in dev version without proguard

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
    @Streaming
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileByUrl(@Url String fileUrl);
}
```